# Do post(io_context, bind_executor(strand, handler)) and post(strand, handler) bear the same results?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Assuming that io_context objects are the same, do

`boost::asio::post(io_context, bind_executor(strand, handler))`

and

`boost::asio::post(strand, handler)`

bear the same results?
I imagine, that the first variant might make an extra call or two. But are there any differences in overall results, i.e `io_context` executes a handler that was ordered by `strand`?

Comment: I do think that the elaborate invocation must increment the work on the "primary" executor even if it's not the one associated with the completion token. That said, you could also `post(bind_executor(strand, handler))` I suppose. (see eg http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/257a8b520f09b8b8)